# requestPermissions() not working for Manifest.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE in API 23

Tags: android, android-permissions

I am facing problem in implementing runtime permissions. I went through below link for implementing runtime permissions:

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

I facing problem for android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE" only. I have tested the below code for CAMERA permission and code working fine for camera permission.

Problem I am facing:

1. shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale() is returning false
2. requestPermissions() not granting permision.

Grade Details: compileSdkVersion 23, buildToolsVersion "23.0.3", targetSdkVersion 23

Manifest Details: I have added the following permission

uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE"

```
    private static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE = 123;  
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        int granted = PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
        int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(ActivityMain.this,Manifest.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE);

    if (result == granted) {
        Toast.makeText(ActivityMain.this,"permissions granted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
    if (result != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Toast.makeText(ActivityMain.this, "permissions denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      boolean res = ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(ActivityMain.this,Manifest.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE);
 // returning false
         if (res) {
           new AlertDialog.Builder(ActivityMain.this)
           .setMessage("Allow")
                  .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                     @Override
                      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ActivityMain.this,
                                new String[]{Manifest.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE},
                              PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE);
                    }
                 }).setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, null).show();
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ActivityMain.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE},
                    PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }
}
    @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
       switch (requestCode) {
           case PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE: {
             if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Toast.makeText(ActivityMain.this,"permissions granted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              } else {
                Toast.makeText(ActivityMain.this,"permissions not granted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MODIFY_PHONE_STATE is a system-only permission, so you can not access or use this permission in your app.

There are 2 types of Android apps: system & user

**System apps** are basically the apps that come pre-installed with your ROM. In a standard Android user environment, the user doesn’t have write access to the /system partition and thus, installing or uninstalling system apps directly isn’t possible.

**User apps** are just all your normal app installations through the Google Play Store. These go into the data partition of your Android phone, which is the part of the internal memory made available for user data and apps.

In order to install an app as a system app on your Android device, your device must either be rooted or have a custom recovery installed (or both).

Comment: But below API 23 we can use this permission by simply declaring in our manifest file so why android not allowing us to use in API 23

Comment: In AndroidManifest. If you declare this permission, you can show the error message on that. It will describe you can't access this permission and more details

Check this [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#MODIFY_PHONE_STATE) mentioned, **Not for use by third-party applications**.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to deal with android Telephony Manager in API 23

Comment: Explain for why you need this function actually

Comment: I want to implement auto pick phone call functionality but on marshmallow I am getting security exception and to overcome this issue I tried to get runtime permission but android not granting modify phone state permission.

Comment: @Sujewan You mean there is not any solutions to endCall programmatically using ITelephony.aidl? So how the Call Blocker Apps do it? Please see my question, too. https://stackoverflow.com/q/50819906/6444297